# Deserialize JSON with User ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am running into an issue while deserializing JSON data. One of the field is the customerID and i cannot find a way to user a Serializer class properly.

Here is my code:

```
class UserProfileData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    captureDateTime = models.CharField(_('Capture datetime'), blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)



class UserProfileDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileData
        fields = "__all__"
```

The JSON i receive is the following:

```
{ "customerID": "someUUID", "captureDateTime": "..." }
```

Here is the current state of my view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_profile(request):    
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = UserProfileDataSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

It fails with the following error:

```
{'user': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

I understand i am missing something here, but can't figure out what... Also, i almost forgot to mention the User object has a customerId field. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change the data being sent so it contains the key "user" instead of "customerID"

Comment: Unfortunatelly, i can't. I am not the one developing that part :(

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument to a field to map it to an attribute with a different name. Something like this should work

```
class UserProfileDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # May want to use a UUIDField based on your question
    # either 'user_id' or 'user' as source
    customerID = serializers.CharField(source='user') # 'user' 

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileData
        fields = ('captureDateTime', 'customerID')
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Now i have another error (which sounds "promissing"...) ValueError: Cannot assign "'1d37334f-6085-4247-9465-e04951663f38'": "UserProfileData.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: @colletjb does changing the field type to PrimaryKeyRelatedField 
 work? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield. I'm assuming the UUID is the user primary key?

Comment: Thanks for your help! re-reading your linked, i concluded i needed the SlugRelatedField. Please find below the solution:

Comment: class UserProfileDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customerId = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='user', queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(), many=False, slug_field='customerId')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileData
        fields = ('captureDateTime', 'customerId')

Comment: @colletjb awesome, do you mind editing this answer with your working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version:

```
class UserProfileDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customerId = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='user', queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(), many=False, slug_field='customerId')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileData
        fields = ('captureDateTime', 'customerId')
```